# xlwings - efficient way to find and replace

Tags: python, excel, replace, xlwings

I am trying to do the below in excel using xlwings

a) Read the input file (which has 15 sheets) `Old_file.xlsx`

b) Find and Replace the keyword `Old Name` with `New Name` (from the python list)

c) I have a python list of new names. So, Save the file with a pattern including {New Name}.xlsx`

So, I tried the below

```
new_names_list = ['Rick','Tom','Joshua']
workbook = xw.Book('Old_file.xlsx') # has 15 worksheets
wks = workbook.sheets
for name in new_names_list:
    for sheet in wks:
        sheet.used_range.api.Replace("Old Name", name)
    file_name = f"FY2022_{name}_Excel_Worksheet_Oct_2022_1.0.xlsx"
    print(file_name)
    workbook.save(r'C:/Users/John/Downloads/files_template/file_name')
```

When I do this, I get the below error and my keyword replacements also doesn't work correctly

> ----------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                  Traceback (most recent call last)  in
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py in save(self, path,
> password)    1063             path = utils.fspath(path)    1064
> with self.app.properties(display_alerts=False):
> -> 1065             self.impl.save(path, password=password)    1066     1067     @property
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py in save(self,
> path, password)
> 801                 ".xla": FileFormat.xlAddIn,
> 802             }
> --> 803             file_format = ext_to_file_format[target_ext]
> 804         if (saved_path != "") and (path is None):
> 805             # Previously saved: Save under existing name
>
> KeyError: ''

Is there any other better way to write this?

**update**

```
File "<unknown>", line 8
    workbook.save(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\files_template\' + file_name)
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: The save **workbook.save(r'C:/Users/John/Downloads/files_template/file_name')** has the variable 'file_name' as part of the path string. **workbook.save(r'C:/Users/John/Downloads/files_template/'+ file_name)**

Comment: do you also know what is wrong with my for loop for keyword replacements? It doesn't replace the word `Old Name` with each of the name from list

Comment: Your sugggestion for path threw `EOL while scanning string liiteral` error. updated the post at bottom

Comment: The line **workbook.save(r'C:/Users/John/Downloads/files_template/' + file_name)**  should work.  The error suggests you have what you are showing in the error **workbook.save(r'C:\Users\John\Downloads\files_template\' + file_name)** using backslashes rather than forward slashes per your original code.

Comment: Now I tried again and it doesn't save the file (but no error). But there is no file saved as well.

Comment: Thanks, I raised an issue in github. For now, I will save it without path. if possible, May I seek your help with for loop for keyword replacements?

Comment: All the 3 files have the same `Rick` keyword but I expect to see `Tom` and `Joshua` in 2nd and 3rd file. We expected keyword `Old Name` to be replaced

Comment: The line **sheet.used_range.api.Replace("Old Name", name)** will work however after the last find/replace it will pop up a message box stating there is no more "Old Name" to be found effectively stopping operation there so nothing will be saved. Probably be an option to suppress but I'd have to look not sure off top of my head.

Comment: Oh I figured out. The issue for replacement is my `Old_file.xlsx` is open only once. So, the changes for 1st round (Rick) is done successfully and saved as a file. For subsequent iterations, there is no `Old Name` because xlwings has already changed it to `Rick` (but not saved it. It is open though). So, code is not able to replace them. So, do I have to open and close everytime in forloop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True the orig workbook doesn't change but what is in memory will and that would be an issue and why the pop up occurred. You could try something like this where you change the name using the previous name as the search string.

In the code below the the first name in the new_names_list is the first search string so we can skip that and loop to the next name.
Then for the first name we want to change 'Rick' we perform the same search/replace but use the previous name in new_names_list as the search string.
For the next name 'Tom' this time we use the previous name 'Rick' as the search string. etc...
So yes no need to re-open the workbook.

```
import xlwings as xw

new_names_list = ['Old Name', 'Rick','Tom','Joshua']
workbook = xw.Book('drop_out.xlsx') # has 15 worksheets
wks = workbook.sheets
for enum, name in enumerate(new_names_list):
    if name != new_names_list[0]:
        for sheet in wks:
            sheet.used_range.api.Replace(new_names_list[enum-1], name)

        file_name = f"FY2022_{name}_Excel_Worksheet_Oct_2022_1.0.xlsx"
        print(file_name)
        workbook.save(r'C:/Users/John/Downloads/files_template/' + file_name)
```

Comment: nice idea. this doesn't require us to open and close `old_file.xlsx` multiple times. Am I right? Only thing is we should include our search term - `Old Name` in new_names_list as well. Right?

Comment: Yep that's what the code above does, I'll some more to the answer if I can

Comment: I changed line 5 to **if name != new_names_list[0]:** since its better way to write that line, not have to change the text in two places if these values change.